# Online machine learning in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I have an ensemebel algorithm in R caret that works fine, but I want to take in account new incoming data. Relearning the algorithm with all the data, new and old, is something I want to avoid.

```
library(caret)
data <- iris
model <- train(Species ~.,data=data[1:145,],method="rf",trControl=trainControl(method="boot",number=10))

## now assume that we get data[146,1:4] after we have completed our model and
## after some time we learn what was the correct outcome. I want to include that
## knowledge into existing algorithm.

# I want to avoid the following call because it is too time consuming;
train(Species ~.,data=data[1:146,],method="rf",trControl=trainControl(method="boot",number=10))
```

I am looking for something like a partial_fit form python SGDClassifier or any other suggestions.

Thanks.

EDIT: I tried to apply help from answer and got this:

```
library(caret)
data <- iris
model <- train(Species ~.,data=data[1:120,],method="rf",trControl=trainControl(method="boot",number=10))
a <- (predict(model,newdata=data[121:150,1:4])==data[121:150,5])
print(a)
previousModel <- model  # load previously saved model object
previousModel$trainingData <- data # change training data to new data
newModel <- update(object = previousModel,forceRefit=T)
b <- (predict(newModel,newdata=data[121:150,1:4])==data[121:150,5])
all(a==b)


 [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[13]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[25]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
### prediction is not perfect
[1] TRUE # after including newdata, nothing changes.. why?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is only a function for updating the Training Parameters:

```
previousModel <- readRDS("....xxx.rds")  # load previously saved model object
previousModel$trainingData <- trainData # change training data to new data
newModel <- update(object = previousModel)
```

Concerning updating based on new Training data, I found an [issue and fix](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/445) for this `train.update` by an Option `forceRefit` with which the model is updated even if there is no Change in the Training Parameters (Code can be seen [here](https://github.com/terrytangyuan/caret/commit/08725fc8df1456c0a0214d87685a7e6f5b98e24fhttps://github.com/terrytangyuan/caret/commit/08725fc8df1456c0a0214d87685a7e6f5b98e24f)).

I hope this helped somehow and you can take it from there.

Comment: Thank you, it is helpful, but I have couple questions:
1. If I try this, why doesnt prediction improve, if I use the newdata for model improvment? code is on edit above

Comment: 2. When I am running a quick check on update.train source code, in the line 40 says "refit the model with new parameters". So doesn't that run another model$fit and that is what is time consuming in the first place?

Comment: to your second question: You re right, but since you first redefined your Training data to the new data, it shouldn't be that time consuming.

Comment: Ok thanks I ll try that. But that brings us to that edit uptop, why doesnt prediction improve when I add newdata?

Comment: Yes I checked but so far I couldn't find the reason myself, sorry.

Comment: You helped a lot, gave me an indea to work on, so thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope this path works out. Would be nice if you kept us updated here as well.